# Jquery Datatable filtering issue with Fixed Header in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-4, datatables-1.10

Please open the [this link](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html) in Internet explorer

select 100 entries from the dropdown and scroll through the records, now try and filter the datatable by entering some text.

Issue: The filter input either doesnt allow me to enter anything after first character or it prepends to the first character. Also the backspace doesnt seem to work..

This issue only occurs in IE.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nightly version of fixedheader js version 3.1.4 and replace h&&h.blur() with if (h) { h.blur();} in that Js file.